# Does university have any cultural mission?

Tags: university

I am asking this question, as my previous [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55791/how-much-is-the-importance-of-campus-life) was closed because of being opinion-based. This made me wonder if there is a conceptual mission for higher education or not?

In most European countries, public universities receive the majority of their budget from the government, as higher education is somehow a public service, and responsibility of the government.

Imagine that all universities in Germany or Sweden decide to abandon any social activities of students. Sell all big campuses and buy modern buildings and only run the educational classes. Then, do the government, parliament, tax payers accept this policy? Is it the university's decision to make or universities have social and cultural responsibility for the society.

It was an exaggerated example, but my point is that:

Are universities simply business entities (even not for profit) to provide a service (which is educational courses) against the money they receive (from tuition or aid).

OR

They have social responsibility to make better citizens beside the professional training.

NOTE: I understand that an urban university may only offer education for a specific range of audience (for example students busy with jobs), but is it acceptable from the fundamental concepts of higher education that a university totally eliminate social activities by assuming that the main responsibility of a university is just providing high quality education.

Comment: "Social activities" at my undergrad uni was almost exclusively binge drinking. I'm glad the university had no official involvement into that. That being said, the content of the courses can make students "better citizens", for example by teaching logic, analysis, etc. it doesn't have to be via "social activities". I'd say your question involves a false dichotomy.

Comment: *only run the educational classes* is standard for many universities in continental Europe.

Comment: Even if we decide education is their sole goal, they should still keep things like university sports and other social activities to encourage a healthy lifestyle (and thus better academic performance) while remaining compatible with the university schedule.

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of this question. If it's asking "Do universities consider that they have a cultural mission", it's a decision that's up to each university (or its overseeing government or other body). Some may consider that they do, others may not. So in that interpretation, there's no general answer. If the question is "*Should* they have such a mission?", it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @NateEldredge With the exaggerated example I clarified my question. Is higher education is considered as a public service (even if private, I mean the government responsibility) like elementary education. OR higher education is a professional service designed for its customers.

Comment: @Davidmh There are some new universities (not many, but increasing), which started with a limited budget and have a limited space in big cities (where there are more potential students). They do not have space or budget for extra-curricula activities.

Comment: I think my issue still stands. Between "public service" and "professional service", each institution gets to set its own priorities. When you ask whether higher education "is considered" to be one or the other: higher education as a whole contains too many disparate elements to be clearly one or the other. The answer also will depend on who's doing the considering.

Comment: If you ask people with some sociological exposure, they'll tell you that "culture" is essentially all our activities interacting with each other as human beings. So, want it or not, universities *are* massively into the "culture" business.

Answer (score 5):

Almost all universities have a larger mission than simply provision of educational courses.  For example, consider the mission statements of two very different publicly funded American institutions:

- [The University of Texas System](https://www.utsystem.edu/about/mission), in addition to education, aims to develop ethics and morals, appreciation of arts and culture, and prepare "educated, productive citizens who can meet the rigorous challenges of an increasingly diverse society and an ever-changing global community"
- [Bunker Hill Community College](http://www.bhcc.mass.edu/about/missionvision/) is much closer to the "pure skills" model, but still also aims to provide community leadership and to ensure that "no eligible student shall be deprived of [education] because of an inability to pay tuition and fees."

In both cases, the university is explicitly aiming to promote social and cultural change towards a society in which most people would generally prefer to live (even though the particular goals of each are different).

Now, mission statements are one thing, reality is another.  Every university's leadership decides how it wants to interpret and/or modify its mission statement. Universities also generally have some sort of board overseeing it, which will attempt to guide and shape the university's actions.  This is where, especially with public universities, there is often a great deal of fighting about the university mission and policies around it.  For example, conservatives who are uncomfortable with the cultural broadening provided by universities often argue that a university should "just stick to teaching skills."  In general, however, the faculty and leadership of most universities tend to promote some sort of cultural mission, [even if some are very different than most](http://www.bju.edu/about/mission-statement.php).

Answer (score 3):

This question seems to relate to a really large and *philosophical* topic. However, if I may compress a comprehensive answer into something more manageable, it might be the following set of points.

In my opinion, all universities (and other educational institutions, for that matter) indeed have a major cultural mission (regardless of public, private, for-profit, non-profit, religious affiliation or lack of it, level of social activities or any other status / attribute). Simply because education's underlying goal is people's **internal** *improvement* and/or *enrichment*, which IMHO is what **culture** all about.

Education is clearly not about learning set of facts, and even not so about helping people to acquire some knowledge, but rather it is about *developing people* into better people, who can then continue *improving themselves, others and the world* around them through *lifetime learning and enrichment*.